# Replace content of Kendo Dialog with a Kendo MVC item?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-treeview

I have this kendo mvc ui item:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Dialog()
  .Name("Details")
  .Title(GetText("menutreeselectionbutton", "Role/ManageRoleTemplates"))
  .Content(
      Html.Kendo().TreeView()
          .Name("menuTreeView")
          .TemplateId("treeview-template")
          .LoadOnDemand(false)
          .AutoScroll(true)
          .DataSource(source =>
          {
              source.Model(model => model.Id("MenuItemId")
                  .HasChildren("HasChildren"))
              .Read(read => read.Action("_GetMenuItems", "Role").Data("GetRoleIdFromHiddenField"))
              .Events(e => e.RequestEnd("requestEndHandler"));
          })
          .ToHtmlString()
    )
  .Visible(false)
  .Modal(true)
  .Width(400)
  .Actions(actions =>
  {
      actions.Add().Text(GetText(Constant.CANCEL, Constant.TEXT_GLOBAL));
      actions.Add().Text(GetText(Constant.SAVE, Constant.TEXT_GLOBAL)).Primary(true).Action("saveMenuTreeSelection");
  }))
```

The idea is that there is a grid with some information, and you can click on a button for each entry that opens up a dialog with the tree view, and you can make some selections there.

Problem is, this treeview is loaded on page load, which spends a lot of unnecessary trips to the backend. It also poses a problem when you close the dialog and open it up for another entry in the grid, because the treeview from the previous selection is shown, while new data is fetched so it can be reloaded.

So I want to load the treeview (or render it) only when the dialog is opened, and "clear" it again when closed.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

I have tried to replace the read action with javascript, but I couldnt get it to work. I also tried replacing the content like so (slightly modified here, for readability):

```
$("#Details").data("kendoDialog").content("@(Html.Kendo().TreeView()
        .Name("menuTreeView")
          .TemplateId("treeview-template")
          .LoadOnDemand(false)
          .AutoScroll(true)
          .DataSource(source =>
          {
              source.Model(model => model.Id("MenuItemId")
                  .HasChildren("HasChildren"))
              .Read(read => read.Action("_GetMenuItems", "Role").Data("GetRoleIdFromHiddenField"))
              .Events(e => e.RequestEnd("requestEndHandler"));
          })
          .ToHtmlString().Replace(Environment.NewLine, ""))");
```

And that "works", but it doesnt render and only displays the raw html code, as shown here:
[image: contents of dialog after setting content from javascript]

I am at a loss. It works fine as is, but not optimal at all.

Comment: Your replacement content doesn't work because you cannot use the MVC wrapper syntax to dynamically add content to the DOM because the MVC wrapper format only works on the server when building a view returned from a controller. You can try using the equivalent javascript jquery syntax instead.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But AFAIK it should work, because all the MVC wrapper does is generate the javascript for you, it just outputs some html and javascript, generated on page load by the server. Once it's generated it's just the same javascript as if you made it yourself. And thats totally fine for what I have in mind. It's just the dialog that displays the raw code. I will update my original post with a screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Came up with a solution of my own. I will just add this for anyone solving something similar, and looking for help.
This is the code for the dialog:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Dialog()
  .Name("Details")
  .Title(GetText("menutreeselectionbutton", "Role/ManageRoleTemplates"))
  .Content(string.Empty)
  .Visible(false)
  .Modal(true)
  .Width(400)
  .Actions(actions =>
  {
      actions.Add().Text(GetText(Constant.CANCEL, Constant.TEXT_GLOBAL));
      actions.Add().Text(GetText(Constant.SAVE, Constant.TEXT_GLOBAL)).Primary(true).Action("saveMenuTreeSelection");
  })
  .Events(e => e
    .Hide("onDialogHide")))
```

Nothing out of the ordinary there.
When a user clicks on the button that display the dialog, in the grid, a function is called where I inject the treeview into the dialog, and then open the dialog, the following is how I save the generated treeview code as a string in javascript and inject it into the dialog (note, surrounding code in the aforementioned method has been removed for readability):

```
$("#Details").data("kendoDialog").content('@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(Html.Kendo().TreeView()
                    .Name("menuTreeView")
                    .TemplateId("treeview-template")
                    .LoadOnDemand(false)
                    .AutoScroll(true)
                    .DataSource(source =>
                    {
                        source.Model(model => model.Id("MenuItemId")
                            .HasChildren("HasChildren"))
                        .Read(read => read.Action("_GetMenuItems", "Role").Data("GetRoleIdFromHiddenField"))
                        .Events(e => e.RequestEnd("requestEndHandler"));
                    })
                    .ToString()))');
```

Notice how I use helpers from Razor (or MVC) to encode the output from Kendo, also changed "ToHtmlString" to "ToString".

To make sure I dont run into trouble from replacing the treeview over and over, I have added an event to the dialog, that cleans up the treeview when the dialog is closed:

```
function onDialogHide(e) {
    $("#menuTreeView").data("kendoTreeView").destroy();
    $("#menuTreeView").remove();
}
```

The "Hide" event is chosen because that is the last event fired by the dialog when it's closed.